# .click() function use with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

JavaScript:

```
<script>

$('#alink').click(function () {
     $("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).show();
 }).ajaxStop(function(){
    $(this).hide();
 });

$('#aresult').load('content2.html', function() {
 $('#successdata').html('100% loaded');
});
 });
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="alink">click me</a>
<div id="aresult"></div>
```

What is the error of this code ?
I want to load ajax call page when user click on the mouse with loading image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do it like this, and avoid the global ajax events:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#alink').on('click', function () {
             $("#loading").show();
             $('#aresult').load('content2.html', function() {
                 $('#successdata').html('100% loaded');
                 $("#loading").hide();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also remember the document.ready function etc.

Comment: The one problem with this is if there are multiple concurrent requests, it will hide `#loading` after the first.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand - There's only one ajax request inside that click function, and everytime you click that link to do that one ajax call the #loading element will show, then hide when the ajax is done. If there where more ajax requests within that click handler, I'm sure that would have been in the question.

Comment: @KayleeMackenzie - Seems to be working just fine to me, it clearly loads "http://www.doers.lk/content2.html", as per my console ?

Comment: yeah it's working .last time i forgotten to end the code with });.now it's also fixed .working fine.is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: It seems fine to me, and this is a common way to do this, so there should'nt be any issues with this way of doing the ajax call etc.